# When to use the method name only and when to invoke the method?

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel. I have been learning relationship for the past few days. I have noticed that when we create a new relationship between two records we invoke the method and than save it.
[image]

But when we are just reading the record of one table through another table with relation, we just use the name of the method.
[image]

So I think that when we need to make changes to records of another table like by creating or editing, we need to invoke the method. But for just reading we only need to call the methods name as a property. Am i right or is there anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to understand why you call the relationship as a property instead of as a method, that's why:

`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`

```php
/**
     * Dynamically retrieve attributes on the model.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __get($key)
    {
        return $this->getAttribute($key);
    }
```

This PHP magic method is called whenever you try to get an instance property which does not exist (a method is not a property, but works likewise thanks to `__call` magic method).
It calls the `getAttribute` from the trait `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes`

```php
/**
     * Get an attribute from the model.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        if (! $key) {
            return;
        }

        // If the attribute exists in the attribute array or has a "get" mutator we will
        // get the attribute's value. Otherwise, we will proceed as if the developers
        // are asking for a relationship's value. This covers both types of values.
        if (array_key_exists($key, $this->getAttributes()) ||
            $this->hasGetMutator($key) ||
            $this->isClassCastable($key)) {
            return $this->getAttributeValue($key);
        }

        // Here we will determine if the model base class itself contains this given key
        // since we don't want to treat any of those methods as relationships because
        // they are all intended as helper methods and none of these are relations.
        if (method_exists(self::class, $key)) {
            return;
        }

        return $this->getRelationValue($key);
    }
```

The last `return` is your answer.